# Trouble reading output console Flutter

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

I'm following the tutorial on flutter_bloc firebase login.
First I tried downloading the repo, adding my reversed Key in the `Info.plist`, my own `GoogleService_Info.plist` and launching the example it works.

Then I started again from scratch, but I get this output which I can't understand and the app doesn't start on iPhone simulator:

> Xcode build done.                                           41.0s
>   Configuring the default Firebase app...
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001082e46fb __exceptionPreprocess + 331  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x0000000107888ac5 objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001082e4555 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197     3   Runner
>   0x0000000103ae64da +[FIRApp configure] + 138  4   Runner
>   0x0000000103bdae86 -[FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin init] + 214    5   Runner
>   0x0000000103bdac38 +[FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin registerWithRegistrar:] +
>   184   6   Runner                              0x0000000103a8bbc0
>   +[GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:] + 112  7   Runner                            <…>

I did put the reverse Key in the `Info.plist` and added my own `GoogleService-Info.plist` file in Runner but my app version doesn't start..
Actually when looking for the URL where to put the reverse Key I didn't see any, so I added it myself. Can it be a lead to where something gone wrong? 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

OK found the problem.. Th `GoogleService-Info.plist` MUST be added to `Runner` through Xcode.. I must have just used Finder instead ..
Hope it helps others
Cheers